# Substitution in determining limit of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, limits-without-lhopital

In my calculus book has been written: "For finding limits sometimes we can change $$\sqrt[m]{a_m x^m + a_{m - 1} x^{m-1} + a_{m - 2} x^{m-2} + \cdots + a_0} $$ to $\sqrt[m]{a_m}\left(x + \dfrac{a_{m - 1}}{ma_m}\right)$ for odd $m$ and $\sqrt[m]{a_m}\left|x + \dfrac{a_{m - 1}}{ma_m}\right|$ for even $m$."

First of all I want to know how these formulas were built. After that , when I can use them without any mistake in value of limit. I searched in the internet but I didn't find these formulas.

Comment: what is $x$ here? That doesn't show up on the left-hand side it seems

Comment: @userSeventeen Yes , I edited it . Thanks !

Comment: and what about the $\ldots$? I don't see a very clear pattern with the coefficients of the $x^i$. Could you give a couple more terms?

Comment: @userSeventeen Is it clear now ?

Comment: Mostly, but I don't think it's true in general. The RHS doesn't even depend on $c,d,\ldots,z$. For example: Just let $m=2$, $x=1=a=b=c$. Then, the LHS is $\sqrt{1^2+1+1}=\sqrt{3}$ while the RHS is $$\sqrt{1}\left(1+\frac{1}{2\cdot1}\right)=\frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: @userSeventeen Yes you are right but for example consider $\lim_{x \to \infty} (\sqrt{n^2 + 3n} - \sqrt{n^2 - 2n}) = \lim_{x \to \infty} ((n + \frac{3}{2}) - (n - 1)) = \frac{5}{2} .$

Comment: Limit as what goes to what? Is $m$ an integer? Is $a>0?$ Come on, let's have some hypotheses.

Comment: @zhw $a , b ,c , \dots z$ are real numbers and $m$ is a natural number.

Comment: And $x\to \infty?$

Comment: @zhw. As I wrote sometimes that substitution has been happened in my book and I saw it as $x$ goes to infinity or minus infinity.

Comment: @zhw. Is it clear now ?

Comment: Well if $a<0,$ $m$ is even, and $x\to \infty,$ this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @zhw. Yes you are right . We should remove that case but what about other cases ? (You can see the example that I wrote above)

Comment: @zhw. Did you find anything ?

Comment: Hi, I'll try to get back to this.

Comment: @zhw. Okay , Thank you a lot .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would strongly advise you against adding such cheap tricks to your bag of tools. It is very unfortunate (for students) that most introductory calculus textbooks tend to provide such non-sense without any justification. I had a lot of struggle with such books in India when I was studying calculus (and I guess your book is also by an Indian author). Almost always such tricks don't provide all the context and the exact rigorous formulation (and the proof).

---

I will state the desired formulas along with proofs below. In what follows $n$ is a positive integer.

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ and assume that $n$ is odd. Also let $a, b$ be the coefficients of $x^{n}$ and $x^{n - 1}$ in $P(x)$ respectively. We thus have $$P(x) = ax^{n} + bx^{n - 1} + Q(x)\tag{1}$$ where $Q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree less than $n - 1$. Then we have the following limit formula: $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{P(x)} - a^{1/n}x = \frac{b}{n}a^{1/n - 1}\tag{2}$$ The proof can be given by putting $t = 1/x$ so that $t \to 0^{+}$ as $x \to \infty$ and hence the desired limit is given by $$\lim_{t \to 0^{+}}\frac{\sqrt[n]{a + bt + t^{n}Q(1/t)} - a^{1/n}}{t}$$ Now we can note that $t^{n}Q(1/t)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ or less which has $t^{2}$ as a factor. So we can write $t^{n}Q(1/t) = t^{2}R(t)$ for some polynomial $R(t)$ of degree less than $n - 1$. Next we put $u = a + bt + t^{2}R(t)$ so that $u \to a$ as $t \to 0^{+}$. We can now see that $(u - a)/t \to b$ and thus the desired limit is reduced to $$\lim_{u \to a}\frac{u^{1/n} - a^{1/n}}{u - a}\cdot\frac{u - a}{t}$$ and this is clearly equal to $b\cdot(1/n)a^{1/n - 1}$ as expected. Here we have used the standard limit formula $$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{x^{r} - a^{r}}{x - a} = ra^{r - 1}\tag{3}$$ which is valid for all values of $r$ and it is this standard limit formula which you should put in your bag of tools.

Some people try to think of equation $(2)$ as meaning $$\sqrt[n]{P(x)} - a^{1/n}x \approx \frac{b}{n}a^{1/n - 1}$$ or $$\sqrt[n]{P(x)} \approx a^{1/n}\left(x + \frac{b}{na}\right)\tag{4}$$ All this is fine upto this point, but a blunder is committed when we say that we can replace LHS of $(4)$ by RHS of $(4)$ while evaluating certain limits. Remember that in *mathematics you can replace a thing $A$ by another thing $B$ only when $A = B$ and not otherwise*. The equation $(4)$ does not describe an equality between two things rather it says that one thing is an approximation of another under certain circumstances. It is however perfectly valid to replace the LHS of $(2)$ i.e. $\lim_{x \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{P(x)} - a^{1/n}x$ by RHS of $(2)$ i.e $(b/n)a^{1/n - 1}$ because these are equal via equation $(2)$.

You should try to formulate and prove the assertion for the case when $n$ is an even positive integer. In this case the leading coefficient of $P(x)$ must be positive.

Comment: Yet another amazing answer. Your answers are without doubt one of the best in explanation in the site, considering you are not a mathematician (Not hard for me to guess why you are not a mathematician).

Comment: The first paragraph single handly worth 1000 upvotes. It is so hard to find a textbook on introductory matter in any subject.

Comment: @A---B: thanks for the compliment! Such words are a big motivation.

Comment: @A---B: I agree with your comment about introductory textbooks. However I got lucky here. I did have to struggle with  many useless calculus textbooks, but after initial few months I got hold of G. H. Hardy's classic *A Course of Pure Mathematics* and after that I never had any doubt in elementary calculus and analysis. The book does away with the need of teachers completely.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you very good answer . So we can always use (2) formula without any doubt ? Is it true when $x \to  -\infty$ ? Can you provide an example that shows approximation can lead us to the wrong answer for calculation limit ?

Comment: @S.H.W: formula $(2)$ can be used all the time and is valid for $x\to -\infty$ also (you should prove this) but it is a simple consequence of formula $(3)$ and you should try to remember and use that.

Comment: @S.H.W: regard the use of approximations, then can be used where we need some approximation for an $n$th root. Since limit evaluations are not about approximations you can't use them in context of limit evaluation. Limits are always evaluated using theorems meant for evaluating limits and these include algebra of limits, squeeze theorem, L'Hospital's Rule, Taylor's theorem and some more specialized theorems.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I'm agree with you but for the exams these ways are important . For example if you want to find $\lim_{x \to \infty} (\sqrt{n^2 + 3n} - \sqrt{n^2 - 2n})$ with theorems , it is taking time but with that method it is very fast

Comment: @S.H.W: The limit you cite is easy and one can almost see that it tends to $(3/2) - (-1) = 5/2$ but not because of such cheap formulas, but via multiplying with conjugate we can see that. Try to use your formula for slightly complicated example like $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\{2n^{2} + 1 - 2n\sqrt{n^{2} + 1}\}$$ Your formula gives the answer $2n^{2} + 1 - 2n\cdot n = 1$ whereas the real answer is $0$.

Comment: @S.H.W: The right way to beat others in exams is to get your basics/fundamentals right. This gives you an edge over your competitors because most students don't bother to get their basics correct and instead are lured by such cheap tricks which don't work all the time. Also note that even if such tricks work in certain cases they are useless in a normal subjective exam where you have to show your approach. Nobody will give you any marks for such tricks.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You're right but there is an exam in my country for going to the university and it has many subjects like math , physics , ... . Also there are 200 questions for answering and for each of them we have just one minute . I like to use exact and complete answers but the exams like this forces me to use faster formulas . If you know a good source for solving question faster that it includes right formulas based on theorems without any doubt please tell me .

Comment: @S.H.W: you can use Taylor series for fast computation and it will never fail (even in the counter-example I gave). Thus we can write $$\sqrt{n^2+2n}=n(1+2/n)^{1/2}=n(1+1/n-1/2n^2+1/2n^3)=n+1-1/2n+\cdots)$$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes , one of the other methods is Taylor series . For example when $x \to 0$ we can substitute $\tan x$ and $\sin x$ with $x$ . And it is obviously wrong in some cases but if you want to write the other terms it takes time . In my book have called these methods (substitutes that I told you ) as Equivalent . I don't know whether it is a mathematics way or not but it is denoted as $\sim$ . For example $\sin x \sim x$ as $x$ goes to zero.